# Apple iOS5 and didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, ios4, ios5, uiapplicationdelegate

I have an iPhone App that uses `UITableViewController` to show a table on the screen. The data of the table (and more data used by the App) is initialized on: `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method of my App Delegate.
The App works perfectly on iOS4. On iOS5, the data of the table doesn't load.
I checked and found that the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method is now called in parallel with showing the view. For this reason, when getting the size of the table, I go to my App Delegate, which still didn't load the table data and therefore return "0".

Is there a way of solving this issue in iOS 5?

Here is the method that gets called first on my view:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    PalmsterAppDelegate *appDelegate = (PalmsterAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    NSLog(@"tableView: %i", [appDelegate.listOfItems count]);
    return [appDelegate.listOfItems count];
}
```

calling: `[appDelegate.listOfItems count]` returns zero. And it clearly shows that the order things is:

`didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` is called (I print to the log on the start of the method).
Then `tableView` is called and prints zero. Then `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` finishes (I print to the log at the end of the method as well).

Comment: Can you show the code from your `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` and the code relating to the loading of your table please?

Comment: What do you mean "called in parallel"? `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` runs on the main thread, as does anything to do with UIKit (e.g. views and view controllers), so they *can't* run in parallel.

Comment: When I do NSLOG on: didFinishLaunchingWithOptions and in: 
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    NSLog(@"tableView: %i", [appDelegate.listOfItems count]);
    return [appDelegate.listOfItems count];
}
This is what I get:
1) didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:start, 2) tableView: 0, 3) didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:end

Answer (score 0):

Move the initialization code into a separate method in your app delegate, and then call that method from the `-viewDidLoad` method of your table view controller.

Make sure you only initialize once, no matter how many times your initialization method is called.

Comment: Good suggestion. I have already tried that :-)  It showed me a blank white screen...

Comment: Weird. That should work in most situations. I would have to guess there is something you're doing in your initialization method that is happening async...? I'd set a breakpoint in your viewDidLoad method and follow it through... see what happens with your NSLogs in relation to your initialization... try to find out why numberOfRowsInSection being called before the initialization is complete... is your UITableViewController in your MainWindow.xib?

Comment: Yes, it is a UITableViewController project. I do nothing async in the AppDelegate. Only initialize the App arrays with data.

Comment: Are you using Core Data? I'm at a loss.

Comment: I do not use Core Data. Actually it is the fist time I hear about. I use simply arrays and NSArrays to hold my information.

Comment: OK. Sorry, I fixed this issue. It was my mistake. I was calling these lines: 1) self.window.rootViewController = self.navigationController 2) [self.window makeKeyAndVisible]; before initializing my data. The question is: Why did it work in iOS4 in the first place... Thanks for your help.

Comment: iOS 5 made a bunch of changes to View Controller structure. I ran into issues when I switched to targeting iOS 5, because they changed the meaning of `UIViewController`'s method `parentViewController`. It's probably something like this...